# What is wrong with pedilanthus?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, fungus

I live in Uttar Pradesh, India and I have planted pedilanthus in my vertical garden. They are in bright indirect sunlight. Their tips are turning pink and there is also some white fungus.
What should I do?

[image: Pedilanthus]

Comment: A close up picture would help